# Adacore GPS "Could not locate executable on path: gnatmake"

Tags: windows, ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I recently installed the Adacore GPS 2012 for Lego Mindstorms on my Windows 7 machine. When I try to build the example project, I get the error message:

"Could not locate executable on path: gnatmake"

I've tried looking for other people with this problem but the majority of these cases are on Linux. If someone could help me figure out the problem, or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you only installed the Mindstorms toolset or is there a native compiler too? I suspect the Mindstorms toolset would include "arm-eabi-gnatmake" or some such to distinguish it from the native compiler. Sorry I don't know GPS well enough to point closer to the answer.

Comment: It sounds like your Ada installation path is not listed in the %PATH% environment variable. Try `echo %PATH%` to see if this is the case, which can be easily solved. Check this first.

Answer (score 0):

"Adacore GPS 2012" is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for ADA development. You also need the ADA compiler. You can find one at [adacore.com](http://libre.adacore.com/download/configurations#). Select `x86-windows` as the platform and download and install the file `gnat-gpl-2013-i686-pc-mingw32-bin.exe`.

Enjoy :)